# Is Google App Engine secure enough for financial applications?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, finance, financial

I am wondering whether Google App Engine is secure enough for financial applications? This would involve storing sensitive information, access to users' funds, etc. Are there any applications like that already running on App Engine?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, App Engine is more secure than most other options.

(1) Google has more people working on security than most companies can afford to work on their own servers or VMs.

When a new security threat is discovered, Google is very likely to fix it quickly, compared to dedicated servers/VMs, where you have to rely on your own sys admin to fix it in time.

(2) There are no OS, firewalls, etc., to configure, which reduces a possibility of a wrong configuration that exposes a security hole. Run times are also limited.

Ultimately, the vast majority of all security breaches happen for two reasons:

- wrong application code/architecture
- human factor (people storing their passwords in email messages, choosing weak passwords, doing harm on purpose, phishing, etc.)

Neither of these factors are any different on App Engine than on any other platform.

As for the second part of your question, Snapchat has a lot of, should I say, very sensitive information. It runs on App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

[Webfilings](https://www.wdesk.com/), a company that handles financial data for most of the Fortune 500, [runs on Google App Engine](https://www.wdesk.com/blog/webfilings-plays-googles-developer-sandbox).  Their statement about it in the second link I've given:

> Google App Engine gave us that speed we needed to grow, but as Murray stated, “being on the Google foundation gives us and our customers peace of mind.” WebFilings needed a platform with a strong approach to security that was very reliable because our customers’ security is a top priority. Because our customers rely on accurate and timely access to the cloud as they input pre-released financial information, security is top-of-mind at our company. As a result, we want our customers’ security to be in the best hands, in Google App Engine’s hands.